# How can I convert PHP Associative Arrays to JSON?

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I'm trying to convert a small JSON to PHP Associative Arrays, but I'm missing a simple thing. Please check the following:

JSON to convert:

```
    $data = '{
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        
        "purchase_units": [{
              "amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": "211.00",
              }
        }],     
    }';
```

My wrong PHP Associative Arrays:

```
$data = array(
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => array(
        "amount" => array(
            "currency_code" => "EUR",
            "value" => "211.00",
        ),
    ),
);
```

My PHP code doesn't let me pass this JSON, there must be a small thing I'm missing. Please could you help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You haven't actually shown any PHP code here, just two different values; one is a string, the other is an array. What is the PHP code you are trying to use this with, and what happens when you try it?

Comment: One more layer of `array()` needed for `purchase_units`. If it helps, write all `{}` as `array()` and all `[]` as `[]`.

Comment: @deceze That looks suspiciously like an Answer.

Comment: @IMSoP He wants an array that will produce the JSON string when you call `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Barmar That's a reasonable guess, but the question doesn't actually say so. I was trying to encourage a bit more effort in describing the problem, rather than risking people wasting their time guessing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `purchase_amounts` should be an array of associative arrays.

```
$data = array(
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => array(array(
        "amount" => array(
            "currency_code" => "EUR",
            "value" => "211.00",
        ),
    )),
);
```

Since PHP allows you to use `[]` notation for array literals, the simplest way to do this is to just copy the JSON. Replace `{}` with `[]` and `:` with `=>`

```
$data = [
        "intent" => "CAPTURE",
        
        "purchase_units" => [[
              "amount" => [
                "currency_code" => "EUR",
                "value" => "211.00",
              ]
        ]],     
    ];
```

Comment: Do you mean `purchase_units` in the first line of your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar, this is the answer that solved my problem, I really appreciated. The first snippet with two array array it works, the second snippet gives me MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON.

Comment: $data = [] in this way works, without the single quotation mark around. Thank you again!

Comment: I forgot to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove unwanted commas at end of purchase_units & amount value

Example

```
$data = '{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    
    "purchase_units": [{
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "211.00"
          }
    }]   
}';
$res = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Not working, MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON. But the one above works.